# How to disable autocomplete in firefox 95 using html . I have tested with autocomplete = off, false, none , Randomstring nothing is working for me

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, autocomplete

How to disable autocomplete in firefox newer version 95 using html or javascript.
I have tested with autocomplete = "off", "false", "none" , "Random string" but None of them is worked for me .

Comment: How is it not working? Please provide more information.

Comment: I am using FireFox version 95 and tried <input type="password" placeholder="" name="psw" id="psw" autocomplete ="off" > but still I could see my old credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, setting `autocomplete` to `off` doesn't stop password managers from filling inputs.

Check the note under "Values":
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: I have tried setting various values mentioned in this link, but the problem is when typing in the password it always gives a prompt which asks to autofill using the stored credentials. Is there a way to disable password manager from storing the credentials? My use case is that I need to do this from the code not from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `autocomplete="off"` onto `<form>` element.